# Use filter on ng-options label - NOT WORKING

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am trying to format a time value from a collection I am using for time within ng-options.

The format in the db is 00:00:00 but I want to present 00:00 AM/PM to the user.

I am trying this;

ng-options="time.time as (time.time | date:'h:mma') for time in times"

With no luck.  Seems like it should be pretty straight forward.  shortTime does not work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a plunkr of the same issue?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AIOkpjQdq5ymaqPkIpzr?p=preview

Comment: `date` filter will work on only `date` object, like here you are trying to make it work on `1.00.00` which is string..

Comment: fair enough.  in my actual app, I am trying to make it work on a collection that is returning a date value like so - 2015-11-05 06:00:00.  Does not work on that either.  Sorry, new to plunker...

Comment: checkout the answer which I've added..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your date should return in correct format so that it would be recognized as `date` by the `date` filter

`2015-11-05 06:00:00` should be changed to `2015-11-05T06:00:00`

```
$scope.times = [
    {time: '2015-11-05T01:00:00', id: '1'},
    {time: '2015-11-05T02:00:00', id: '2'},
    {time: '2015-11-05T03:00:00', id: '3'},
    {time: '2015-11-05T13:00:00', id: '4'},
];
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/e2wSNsNULaZhfzgrMFe6?p=preview)